# Checking checkbox inside table in swt

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

I have a table with checkboxes inside my table but the problem is when i ticked the checkbox it doesn't print the value of the data but when I unchecked the box using double clicked it prints and the output is doubled where it shouldn't be printing.

```
output: 
SCKS-006 , 1108 , 10.199.25.101
SCKS-006 , 1108 , 10.199.25.101
```

and i have this code (i got it from here in SO)

```
Table table = (Table) e.widget;
            TableItem item = table.getItem(table.getSelectionIndex());
            for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
            {
                if(item.getChecked())
                {
                    item.setChecked(false);
                    System.out.println(item.getText(0) + " , "+ item.getText(1) + " , "+ item.getText(2));
                }
                else
                    item.setChecked(true);
            }
```

Comment: Show us a [mcve]

Comment: what do you mean by that sir? @greg-449

Comment: Read the link. Provide us with code we can test.

Comment: Provide code for your checkboxes, you just have `TableItem`. BTW you should use selection listener for check boxes to produce the output based on selection of check box instead of checking `getChecked()`